# Prevent hover effect to first element through css

Tags: css

I am trying to prevent the hover and focus effect only on first row, but when I am applying "first-child" pseudo code it applies to all the rows.. Here's the code:

```
/* CSS */
ul {list-style-type: none;}
ul > li > a {
    background: transparent;
    font: normal 12px Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #007DBD;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    width:200px;
}

ul > li > a:first-child {
    color:#333;
    background: none;
}

ul > li > a:hover, ul > li > a:focus {
    color: #009BE1;
    background: #F3F3F3;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* HTML */
<ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">sample@test.com</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">Edit Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

I don't want any hover effect for first `<li><a>` item. 
Here's the js-fiddler: 
http://jsfiddle.net/123qyrtc/

Please let me know if there is any CSS solution...

Comment: first-child should be applied to the <li> not the <a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
ul > li:first-child > a:hover, ul > li:first-child > a:focus {
    color:#333;
    background: none;
    text-decoration:underline
}
```

Comment: Its working in all browsers... I was applying not(first-child) to <a> instead of <li>... Thanks for your help http://jsfiddle.net/123qyrtc/7/

Answer (score 3):

Use the `:not()` pseudo to exclude what you don't want:

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/123qyrtc/3/)

```
ul > li:not(:first-child) > a:hover, ul > li > a:focus {
    color: #009BE1;
    background: #F3F3F3;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Just remember that the `:first-child` in this case is the `<li>`, not the `a`. The `a` is always first.

Comment: @Brent - That was never a requirement, was it? ;)

Comment: Not a requirement, but wouldn't you want it to work in all browsers?

Answer (score 3):

To clarify, you don't want the first part (sample@test.com) to have a hover effect, correct? You need to target the first li then, like so:

```
ul > li:first-child > a:hover {
    color:#333;
    background: none;
}
```